# RTL label won't show over the input field

Tags: html, label, bootstrap-4, input-field

I'm using a Bootstrap 4 theme in my website, by using the [Material Dashboard Pro](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-pro) from Creative Tim.
I have an input field with a label for it. When there is no text in the field, the label will be shown over the field. When the user enters some text into the field, the label should jump above the field.

When the website is in English, it works well:
[image]

But when I'm running it in Hebrew, the label jumps to the left of the field, outside of it:
[image]

As you can see, when the label is in Hebrew, the label won't show inside the input field, but outside.

This is my code for the field:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="bmd-label-floating">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NAME">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this so it'll work both for English and Hebrew?

Comment: can you share your css?

Comment: which browser you use? its work fine for me..

Comment: @YusefTukachinsky I'm using Google Chrome